# how to style rails's 'number_field_tag'?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

had not been able to find anything that i need from this.
attached image below is form default generated in rails 4 when "number_field_tag" is used.

is there anyway to style it with CSS? i cant seem to found any guide on this.
if it can't be styled with CSS, i will explore on CSS + javascript from scratch. appreciate the inputs!

### Default Form from "number_field_tag" in Rails

[image]

Comment: How would you like it to look like? You mean the input itself or those arrows from the right?

Comment: Preferrable those arrows on the side. Would like to style them to have left and right with + - signs, clicking will have incremental function on the value..

Comment: There is not much you can do (check https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/). You could use a regular text input and two buttons (for + - signs), style them and use javascript to validate input.

Comment: wow that is a bummer.. anyway thanks for the heads up. been researching CSS + Javascript for this feature. such an amount of code just for this simple feature =.=

Comment: Yes, but most of the code will go to CSS anyway, if you use jQuery you can get away with it with just a few lines. Check my answer below with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this, `nil` is the default value here

```
= number_field_tag :some_field, nil, class: 'some-class'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't alter styling in any way, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your styling using text `input` and `button` elements instead of `number_field_tag`.

You can add as much style as you want (you can even enclose everything within a `div` tag an style it) and you only need to control the value increments. If you add `readonly` attribute (as i did), you don't even need to check if the value is a number.

Check this simple demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#minus').on('click', function() {
    $('#number').val(function(i, value) { return --value });
  });

  $('#plus').on('click', function() {
    $('#number').val(function(i, value) { return ++value });
  });
});
```

```css
.number-button, .number-input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.number-input {
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="minus" class="number-button">-</button>
<input type="text" id="number" class="number-input" value="0" readonly />
<button id="plus" class="number-button">+</button>
```